# Problems with DrJava's interactions pane, eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drjava

I am using DrJava's plugin for Eclipse (4.3), and the interactions pane "view" is acting funny.
(Very similar to [this guy](http://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/support-requests/269/) from 2011). Unfortunately, his question has no responses.

I also found [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/mailman/message/337097/), however it's from 2004, and hasn't solved my problem.

DrJava refuses to acknowledge or instantiate objects, even though it throws no error.

```
Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\Users\Raghav
> int j = 4
> j
4
> import javax.swing.*;
> JFrame j = new JFrame();
> j
4
>
```

I'm not sure why this happens, as it does not give an error on the import.

I also tried this:

```
Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\Users\Raghav
> import javax.swing.*;
> JFrame s = new JFrame()
> s
Static Error: Undefined name 's'
```

To be sure it was a problem with the plug in, and not java itself, I entered the same code into the interactions pane in drjava (20130901-r5756). It worked as expected here:

```
Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\Users\Raghav
> int j = 4
> j
4
> import javax.swing.*;
> JFrame j = new JFrame()
> j
javax.swing.JFrame[frame0,0,0,0x0,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
```

So I have two questions:

1. How can I fix the plug-in not acknowledging the creation of objects?
2. Is there anyway to change the working directory in the plugin? I've only found this possible in Dr.Java IF a new Project is created, or under Preferences -> Resources -> Extra ClassPath. This is because I have different projects in different folders, and I'd like to test the classes, but I can't change my classpath to their location.

This is my first post on SO, please let me know if this questions needs any edits, or is not clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you filed a bug at drjava.org?  Please try re-installing from scratch on a plain-vanilla system first.  I'd recommend using a VM for this.  I bet they'll ask you if you've done this, and I've heard Eclipse can be quite sensitive to other software.